# Hadoop command error

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop-2.4.0 on sigle node cluster. After starting the dfs and yarn and executing the jps I get the following services running..

```
6584 ResourceManager
5976 NameNode
6706 NodeManager
6407 SecondaryNameNode
6148 DataNode
7471 Jps
```

When I try to execute the following command I get the error

*hduser@dhruv-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /hello*

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VMwarning: You have loaded llibrary
>   /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0  which might
>   have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack' -c
>   ', or link it with '-z noexecstack. 14/10/22 12:21:36 WARN
>   util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin java classes where applicable.

Can please somebody suggest me, what is wrong and how to rectify this ?

Thanks
Dhruv

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore that if you want. It means that you are running a 32-bit native libraries on a 64-bit runtime.
If the log still annoys you, then you need to build those native libraries on a 64-bit environment.

Comment: Hi Chiron, how to rebuild the native libraries on 64 bit env.Becuase without doing this, hadoop commands would not run.

Comment: @user1920851 You can google for that topic. I might be wrong but I'm sure that Hadoop commands is still running and you can ignore the warning.